# Bootstrap Popover Input Field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to trigger a popover event when a user clicks in an input field, then disable it when the user clicks in another field? Here's what I have, but it does not disable when the user clicks in another field.

```
 <input id="example" />

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function ()  
      { $("#example").popover({title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover', content: "It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!"});  
    });  
   });
 </script>
```

How can I make this popover disable when the user clicks in another input field? Thank you!

Comment: A note, `$(handler)` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(handler)`, so there's no need to use both: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One simple way of hiding it would be to subscribe to `blur`:

```
$(function () {
    $("#example")
        .popover({ title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover', content: "It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" })
        .blur(function () {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 16):

I made some testing with Christoffers answer and got it minimized:

```
$('#element').popover({ trigger: 'focus', title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover', content: "It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" })
```

Comment: Added bonus; the popover doesn't disappear when you click the input field twice. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 8):

I think its easier if you use HTML5:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').popover();
}

<input id="example" type="text" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="right" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the "popover" using "trigger"!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(function ()  
     {
         $("#contato").popover({title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover', trigger: 'focus', content: "It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!"});  
     });  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your link is

```
<a href="#foo" id="bas">bar<a>
```

you can hide the popover by simply adding the following js:

```
$('#bas').on('click',function() {
    $('#example').popover('hide');
});
```